# Can I throw an exception when mapping a DBNull with Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Let's assume that I have a class model that I would like to have non-default values in

```
public class MyModel()
{
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public int? PropertyTwo { get; set; }
    public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say that I query for MyModel with this query

```
SELECT
   NULL as PropertyOne,
   NULL as PropertyTwo,
   NULL as PropertyThree
```

If I map this to MyModel class, I will have PropertyOne = 0, PropertyTwo = null, PropertyThree = null.

By default Dapper will not call any setters if it encounters a DBNull value when reading, so PropertyOne has a default value of an int which is 0.

1. I don't want that, I would like to verify that I would always get a non-null value for PropertyOne from my query and I'd like to get an exception if the reader encounters a DBNull.
2. Let's say that I also don't want to have a null value for PropertyThree. Can I also achieve this check somehow with Dapper when mapping happens? And can I do this by using an attribute like in the model below?

```
public class MyModel()
{
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public int? PropertyTwo { get; set; }
    [NotDBNull]
    public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
}
```

So ideally what I want to achieve is use the above model and have the following logic:

Case 1: PropertyOne gets DBNull, but it's not nullable => throw an exception

Case 2: PropertyTwo gets DBNull, but it's nullable => all good

Case 3: PropertyThree gets DBNull, but is marked with [NotDBNull] attribute => throw an exception

Is there any way that I can achieve this with Dapper without using other forms of validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper.AOT works (I hope! It is meant to) in the way you describe, for both value-types and reference-types (the latter if NRTs are enabled in the source).

It isn't possible for me to know from your code whether NRTs are enabled, but:

- `string` with NRTs enabled means "actively expect non-null"
- `string?` with NRTs enabled means "allow null"
- `string` without NRTs enabled means "allow null"
- `int` means "actively expect non-null"
- `int?` means "allow null"

So: [try Dapper.AOT](https://aot.dapperlib.dev/gettingstarted) and see how it goes! Depending on feedback we may add an attribute to soften this behaviour back to Dapper vanilla's null handling, but: what you describe is how we *want* things to work going forward.

Comment: Thanks, Marc! I should've indeed clarified that the project and the example wasn't using NRTs. I will try it out to see how well it works and wether it can be easily retro-fitted. One thing that I've notcied from the doc is that it replaces the old reflection-based mapping with interceptors. So if I understand it correctly, I'll also not be able to use existing ITypeMapper and ITypeHandler implementations, right? Assuming yes, is there a way to map a property to a db column that exists for the code-gen (something like a [DBColumn(Name = "Col1")] on a property)?

Comment: @AntonZhernosek yes, `[Column(...)]`